# Are controls customizable on the Xbox 360 Edition of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm asking because of [this comment](http://www.youtube.com/comment?lc=C7EjpXlL_EUyu1naYVumt7P6AOVY6iB_mxBQXbaDOTs):

> Can you modify the controls in Minecraft 360 edition? I'm disabled and can't press the left trigger, so I don't want to buy the game if the controls aren't customizable. Pretty pointless if I can't place blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No

There are only 3 preset control layouts

I have taken pictures of the layouts (sorry for quality)

Layout 1

[image: Layout 1]
Layout 2

[image: Layout 2]

And layout 3
[image: l]Layout 3]
Source: I took the pictures above